# Pass data with PendingIntent and retrieve with onNewIntent when app launches

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, onnewintent

I have an Android application which will receive push notification. The notification have wearable support hence the notification will also be visible in Android wear with action button.

I am looking to pass data when the notification reaches `onMessageReceived` in `FirebaseMessagingService` class. Tried setting data in Intent and passed that with Pending Intent.

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("12345")
        intent.putExtra("user_id", "USER ID")
        intent.putExtra("date", "DATE")
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext,
            System.currentTimeMillis().toInt() , intent,
            0
        )
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel =
                NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    CHANNEL_NAME,
                    CHANNEL_IMPORTANCE)
            val notificationManager =
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

            val notificationBuilder =  NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .extend(NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                    .addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.icon,
                        "Explore",
                        pendingIntent))
                )
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
```

When click on the notification from Wear, capturing the intent in `onNewIntent` to get the data passed. But couldn't find the data which were passed.

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    setIntent(intent)
    // intent.getStringExtra("date")
    // intent.extras.getString("date")
    // intent.extras.get("date")
    // intent.data
}
```

Couldn't get the data. Is there any way to get the intent passed with the pending intent ? Or how to get the values passed with Pending Intent.

Comment: Is `onNewIntent()` being called? Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that `onNewIntent()` is not being called.

If you specify `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and your app is already running and there is an instance of `MainActivity` in the task stack, Android will remove the existing instance of `MainActivity` and create a new one. The `Intent` with "extras" will then be delivered in `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` will not be called.

If your app is not running, tapping the notification will start your app and create a new instance of `MainActivity` and the `Intent` with the "extras" will be delived in `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` will not be called.

Also, since the `Intent` that you put in the `PendingIntent` will be used by Android to launch an `Activity` from a non-`Activity` context, you need to specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Also, you should always specify `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when getting a `PendingIntent` with "extras", because if you do not, you may get an existing `PendingIntent` with some old "extras" or maybe none at all. Using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will ensure that your `Intent` "extras" are copied into the `PendingIntent` even if it already exists. Like this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("12345")
    intent.putExtra("user_id", "USER ID")
    intent.putExtra("date", "DATE")

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        System.currentTimeMillis().toInt() , intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
```